# play wav file with jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, wav, jplayer

I am using the Jplayer plugins for playing audio files. It play mp3 file but does not support the wav audio file. I have searched the reason and came to know that wav audio file should be of specific format to be played with flash or HTML 5. But My wav files are of bit rate 64 kbps. How can I play this format wav audio file for example converting wav to suitable format and play that file. Is there any plugins to play any format of wav file or plugins to convert wav to suitable format to be able to play file or any alternatives? What should be bit rate to be able to play with JPlayer plugins.

I have following codes for playing wav file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"play.mp3",
                wav:"testtest.wav"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3, wav, m4a, oga",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download SOX at http://sox.sourceforge.net/ to convert your wav file to different bit rate needed.

Try this conversion syntax: `sox input.wav -t raw -r 8000 -e a-law -b 16 -c 1 output.wav` and test it with FireFox to see. Good luck!